# How to make a Haml form with two conditional actions

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

On submit this form will call the `put` action on the controller:

```
.panel-body{style: 'background:#0E0D0D;'}
    =form_for @payment, method: :put, html: {id: 'edit_bank_detail'} do |f|          .row.text_white
      .form-group.col-lg-12
        =f.label :paypal_email_address
        =f.email_field 'user_paypal_email',class: 'form-control'
    .row.text-center
      .form-group.col-lg-12
        =f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary text_black',data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." }
```

I need it to call the `put` or `create` action based on the condition:

```
if @payments.new_record? 
  # create action
else
  # put action
```

Comment: If the only thing that changes is the method, which is a symbol, you can use a ternary operator `(@payments.new_record? ? :post : :put)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".
Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.
You're asking us to teach you how to write code, but on Stack Overflow we want you to try writing it, then we'll help fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this and it works.

```
 =f.submit 'Submit', action_name: @return.new_record? ? 'create' : 'update'
```

Thanks [@Sebastian Palma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5025116/sebastian-palma) followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to specify the HTTP method in the first place. `form_for` and its successor `form_with` are smart enough to figure out both the path for the action attribute and the method by calling `#persisted?` on the `@payment` model instance that you pass as the first argument.

```
= form_for @payment, html: {id: 'edit_bank_detail'} do |f|
```

Given conventional routes this will point the form to `POST /payments` or `PATCH /payments/:id` if the record has been persisted. Rails has used PATCH instead of PUT for updates [since 2012](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/26/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/) but `resources` and `resource` still generate additional `PUT` routes for backwards compatibility.